# CocoaPods update RestKit #import "RKObjectMapping.h" file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, rkobjectmapping

I want to update some of my project pods and after run pod update "some_framework" and try to build project appear this error:

> ## import "RKObjectMapping.h" file not found

Current CocoaPod version is **0.39.0** I have tried to downgrade to **0.38.2** and lower but without any success, **XCode** version is **6.4** I have tried to change configuration of search path in Build Setting from non-recursive to recursive but again without success.

So I don't know what to do next, because I need to do some updates in project and **RestKit** is main framework for working with server side.

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
platform :ios, '7.1'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.1'
pod 'EZForm', '~> 1.1.0'
pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.0'
pod 'ImoDynamicTableView', '~> 1.1.273'
pod "ImoDynamicPopUp"
pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.6'
```

This is how error looks like, in Xcode: [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXTS.png)

Comment: what does your podfile contain ?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: There's a commit waiting to be merged in that fixes this issue, will be v0.26.0

Comment: @Wain any ideas when will this happen?

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party,I had same issue with cooca pod 0.39.0 and restkit 0.24.1 updated restkit to 0.26.0 and issue was fixed

Answer (score 3):

Imports in public header files should be `#import <RestKit/Subdirectory/RKHeader.h>` instead of `#import "RKHeader.h"`

This is required for **RestKit** to be compatible with future CocoaPods version because of CocoaPods/CocoaPods#4057 (The **HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS** will no longer be constructed recursively) introduced in **0.39.0.beta.1**.

Comment: My restkit import looks like `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but the easiest way to fix this is to add `${PODS_ROOT}` (and set it to recursive) in `Header Seach Paths` under `Build Settings` in your target settings.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue few days ago. It seems that I had two CocoaPods version 0.39.0 and 0.38.2. When I removed 0.39.0 and updated pods it worked.
Use `gem list` in terminal to see installed gems.

Comment: I have did how you wrote and I have other error


`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

  "_RKLogCoreDataError", referenced from:

      ___33-[RKEntityByAttributeCache load:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKEntityByAttributeCache.o)

      ___43-[RKManagedObjectImporter finishImporting:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKManagedObjectImporter.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) `

Comment: maybe try to remove cocoapods and reinstall them, and remove DerivedData, module cache, reload Xcode etc. This kind of mistakes sometimes happens with RestKit.

Comment: I have tried to to do all you propose, and didn't help :( I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: Long ago I also had the same issue with `RKObjectMapping.h`, and it wasn't problem with pods. But next day it disappeared, even I hasn't made any changes. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I did use 0.26.0 version of Restkit but 0.38.2 of cocoa pods. The only thing I'd to change after was selecting  "**Project Pods**", and in "**Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only**" change to **NO**

---

**[UPDATE]!!!!**
You can now follow the answer from [@sajjon](https://github.com/Sajjon) in this post from [github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2356) to use cocopods versions: 0.39.0, 1.0.0 and 1.0.1

> if anyone is having problems with RestKit 0.26.0 and Cocoapods 1.0.1,
> hopefully this will help!
>
> This solution worked at least on 2016-06-03, but since it uses
> specific git branches maybe these will be merged, so if this does not
> work for you please check if this git branches have been
> merged/moved/deleted.
>
> Clean up before everything
>
> Quit Xcode
>
> ```
> rm -rf Pods 
> rm -rf MyApp.xcworkspace   
> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods 
> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
> ```
>
> **[Use mcfedr's RestKit fork](https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit/tree/pods1)**
>
> Must be used together with "reachablility" branch of AFNetworking
>
> ```
> pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/mcfedr/AFNetworking.git', :branch =>
> 'reachability' 
> pod 'RestKit', :git => 'https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit.git', :branch => 'pods1' Use module
> ```
>
> **import syntax in Bridging Header**
>
> ```
> @import RestKit;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to Cocoapods 1.1.1 and RestKit 0.26.0 and it works fine.

Comment: Works for me. Zanks!

Comment: Good to know !!